# Kubernetes Fabric8 API

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, fabric8

I currently use the fabric8 API to read contents of PODs, Services etc.

```java
KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
client.configMaps().withName("ConfigMapName");
```

Is there a way to retrieve contents of HTTPProxy from httpproxies  of api group                            projectcontour.io?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please summarise the problem in the title, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTPProxy` seems to be a [Custom Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/). Kubernetes Client provides a [Typed API](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#customresource-typed-api) (where you need to provide POJOs for your Custom Resource) and a [Typeless API](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#customresource-typeless-api)(manipulation of Custom Resouces using raw HashMaps). Here is an example on how you can do this using the Typeless API:

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    CustomResourceDefinitionContext httpProxyContext = new CustomResourceDefinitionContext.Builder()
            .withGroup("projectcontour.io") // <-  Group of Custom Resource
            .withVersion("v1")              // <-  Version of Custom Resource
            .withPlural("httpproxies")      // <-  Plural form as specified in CRD
            .withScope("Namespaced")        // <-  Whether Custom Resource is Cluster Scoped or Namespaced
            .build();

    // List all HTTPProxies
    Map<String, Object> httpProxyList = client.customResource(httpProxyContext).list("ns1");
    // Get a specific HTTPProxy
    Map<String, Object> myHttpProxy = client.customResource(httpProxyContext).get("ns1", "tls-example");
}
```

You may choose whatever approach you think fits your needs. If interested you can probably check out my blogs about these approaches in detail:

1. [Handling Kubernetes Custom Resources in Java using Fabric8 Kubernetes Client: Part-1(Typeless)](https://medium.com/@rohaan/handling-kubernetes-custom-resources-in-java-using-fabric8-kubernetes-client-249c4fe01d27)
2. [Handling Kubernetes Custom Resources in Java using Fabric8 Kubernetes Client: Part-2(Typed)](https://medium.com/@rohaan/handling-kubernetes-custom-resources-in-java-using-fabric8-kubernetes-client-part-2-typed-cc0560d9af0d)